# Adding HTML into an iTextPDF PdfPCell

Tags: itext7

What is the up-to-date method of using an HTML string in a table cell using iText7 (iTextPDF) PdfPCell?

```
    private PdfPCell makeHTMLCell(String htmlString)
    {
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
          List<IElement> list = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(htmlString); 
          Iterator<IElement> listIter = list.iterator();
          while (listIter.hasNext())
          {
            Paragraph p = (Paragraph)listIter.next();
            cell.addElement(p);
          }
          return cell;
    }
```

I'm getting a class cast exception when I try to map the element to a Paragraph.  I'm making a mistake here in how I process the HTML IElement list to add it to a PdfPCell